# PHP Google App Engine - File Upload Giving Error

Tags: php, google-app-engine

When I try to upload a file using the method given in the Google App Engine documentation I am getting this error,

Notice: Undefined index: content-type in /google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_MediaFileUpload.php on line 99 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_MediaFileUpload.php:99) in ajax-processing-functions.php on line 64

When I checked on Google_MediaFileUpload.php:99 Its checking the content type of the file that is uploaded. Its looking at the MIMEType property. But there is no way to set this value. How to do it?

Comment: You seem to be using an outdated version of Google Api Client. Give this one a try instead: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in my google app engine to accomplish a file upload. You do not need any extra files. This should work right out of the box on a fresh PHP Google App Engine website.

**FILE UPLOADER**

```
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'bucket' ];
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload.php', $options);
```

Then, have your form be like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $upload_url; ?>" method="post">
```

Then in **upload.php**, have the following
(notice `upload_file` is whatever your input name is for your file attachment):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'], 'gs://bucket/new_file.pdf');
```

Now, the file is in your bucket and you can do whatever you want with it.